# How to work with the individual digits of an int in C++?

Tags: c++

I have an assignment that involves writing a (very limited) LargeInt class. For the constructor, I'm trying to make it so the user can input a very large int and the constructor will record that int into an array, each element holding one digit. Because we're talking hundreds of digits, I do not want the user to have to use delimiters or type the number digit-by-digit, I simply want the user to be able to type, say

> 123456789...n

and the constructor writes this to an array where a[0]=1, a[1]=2, a[2]=3, and a[3]=4, etc. The end goal is actually an array storing the user's int backwards, so that I can overload + and add two LargeInts, but I already have an algorithm for copying and reversing an array.

Anybody have any insight? I'm really pretty new to C++ and there's still a *lot* to learn...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Read as chars in a loop or once into a string then write the code to integers into your array.

Comment: Why not use string datatype, no need to reverse and has many inbuilt functions.

Comment: There's no need to use an array. Just use a `std::string`, both as a constructor argument and as a private data member. Use `std::getline` to read a line of user input into the `std::string` which is then passed to the constructor.

Comment: I'm not sure what "user input" you mean. Do you mean input from the console or to allow a programmer using a constructor like LargeInt(9876543210123456789) ?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the constructor accept an array of characters, or even better, use std::string:

```
class BigInteger {
public:
    BigInteger(const std::string& s) : m_s(s) {}
    //...

private:
    std::string m_s;
};


int main() {
    BigInteger n("123456789");
    //...
}
```